# Reloading a Maven dependency at runtime

Tags: java

I'm attempting to re-load at runtime a Maven dependency. The reason for this is I have a set of dependencies that load their own configuration, each of these dependencies can overwrite each others configuration depending on how they are loaded. I can view the loaded configuration via a method call : `getConfig()` . I want to determine at runtime how loading each dependency alters the configuration returned by `getConfig()`, therefore re-load at runtime a Maven dependency.

[In Maven, how can I dynamically build a property value at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002033/in-maven-how-can-i-dynamically-build-a-property-value-at-runtime) references building a property at runtime, also can lookup dependencies at runtime : [Maven - lookup dependencies at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977979/maven-lookup-dependencies-at-runtime) ut I'm unable to find docs relating to reloading a dependency at runtime

Comment: Not practical. You can't explicitly unload a class from a classloader. By the way, Maven is a built tool so is completely irrelevant at runtime. I wouldn't be including 'Maven' in your search terms anywhere.

Comment: Seems like you are more interested in an OSGi solution rather than a Maven build tool solution